# "Undefined" Group Label in Vue-Multiselect?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, multi-select

I am new to Vue and have improved this code from various tutorials.

However, I am faced with this "Undefined" group name issue here.

**.html:**

```
<multiselect 
    v-model="value" 
    :options="options"
    :multiple="true"
    track-by="name"
    :hide-selected="true" 
    :custom-label="customLabel"
    :searchable="false" 
    placeholder="" 
    group-values="details" 
    group-label="groupDivision"
    >
  </multiselect>
```

**.js:**

```
new Vue({
    components: {
    Multiselect: VueMultiselect.default
    },
    data: {
    value: { groupDivision: 'Government', 
            name: 'Fish', 
            contact: 'Fish@.com' },

    options: [

      { 
        groupDivision: 'Governemnt',
        details:[
        {   name: 'Fish', contact: 'Fish@.com' },
        { name: 'Police', contact: 'Police@.com' },
        { name: 'Society', contact: 'Society@.com' }
        ]  
      },
       { 
        groupDivision: 'Media',
        details:[
        {   name: 'BBC', contact: 'BBC@.com' },
        { name: 'CNN', contact: 'CNN@.com' },
        { name: 'CBC', contact: 'CBC@.com' }
        ]  
      },
    ]
    },
  methods: {
    customLabel (option) {
      return `${option.name}`
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

I've already set the "**group-label**" but it still shows "undefined".

Does anyone have idea what the problem? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Link to the code:
https://codepen.io/dennis-leeyinghui/pen/VzybrR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue already fixed [here](https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect/commit/3a6c6ef5e222ffc59b58a20f950773d087399376),

replace your `vue-select` with this instead:

```
https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.0-beta.15/dist/vue-multiselect.min.js
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be [a bug fixed in v2.0.2](https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect/commit/3a6c6ef5e222ffc59b58a20f950773d087399376), your code played well with latest vue-multiselect.
Check webpackbin [here](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KrjW8Zx244l7Ua-ZfOC).

Comment: Thanks! First time running into a bug lol Do you think there is anything I can do in CodePen to work around the issue?

Comment: kevlai22 already pointed it out. Just use `https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.0-beta.15/dist/vue-multiselect.min.js`

Comment: I got the answer from kevlai22. Thanks very much though :D

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Received undefined without using group-Division etc. my use-case was using a simple custom-label. I even tried to update the multiselect library to 2.02 as suggested by the correct answer selected and yet didn't work.

Here's what worked for me. I changed my vue js package from vue2.5 to vue 2.6.11 and it began to work.